# How to Send Form Data to My Email using Form Script

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this webpage where there is this form code which gets submitted successfully but not sure where it is sending the data. I want to change it to send the data to my email instead. I am no programmer so don't know what is going on in this code script below .

```
<!--form script-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#box-slider').each(function() {

                var self = $(this),
                    get_item = $('#box-slider .item'),
                    get_item_length = get_item.length,
                    indicators = $('#box-slider .carousel-indicators'),
                    index = "0";
                indicators.find('li:first').addClass('active');
                get_item.first().addClass('active');

                get_item.each(function(i) {
                    get_item_name = $(this).find('img').data('name');

                    indicators.find('li:eq(' + i + ')').html(get_item_name);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js" integrity="sha256-1A78rJEdiWTzco6qdn3igTBv9VupN3Q1ozZNTR4WE/Y=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Get the old visit count, or 0 if this is his first time
            var visits = $.cookie("visits") || 0;
            if (visits == 0) {
                visits++;
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1200 * 1000));
                $.cookie("visits", visits, {
                    expires: date
                });
                var xmlhttp;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                    }
                }
                //Change Project Name and URl here

            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code for the form or the form function SendQueryData() if that helps -

```
function SendQueryData() {
            //Form No 103
            var vAgentID = 4381; //Change Agent Code
            var vProjectName = "Supertech Hypernova"; //Change Project Name ( note more then 30 character)
            var vSenderName = '';
            var vMobileNo = '';
            var vEmailID = '';
            var vCityName = '';
            var vQueryMessage = '';
            var vMicrositeUrl = document.documentURI;
            // var vURL = '';
            // var APIProjectName = '';


            vSenderName = document.getElementById("qSenderName");
            vMobileNo = document.getElementById("qMobileNo");
            vEmailID = document.getElementById("qEmailID");
            vQueryMessage = document.getElementById("qQueryMessage");
            // APIProjectName = document.getElementById("project_name");
            // vURL = document.getElementById("url");




            if (vSenderName.value == "" || vSenderName.value.length == 0) {
                alert("Please enter Sender First ");
                vSenderName.focus();
                return false;
            } else if (vMobileNo.value == "" || vMobileNo.value.length == 0) {
                alert("Please enter Mobile No ");
                vMobileNo.focus();
                return false;
            } else if (vMobileNo.value.length <= 9) {
                alert("Please enter Valid Mobile No ");
                vMobileNo.focus();
                return false;
            } else if (vEmailID.value == "" || vEmailID.value.length == 0) {
                alert("Please enter Email ID ");
                vEmailID.focus();
                return false;
            } else if (vQueryMessage.value == "" || vQueryMessage.value.length == 0) {
                alert("Please enter Query text. ");
                vQueryMessage.value.focus();
                return false;
            }
            var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
            if (vEmailID.value.match(emailExp) == null) {
                alert("Invalid E-mail Address! Please re-enter ?");
                return false;
            } else {

                setProjectQueryData(vAgentID, vProjectName, vSenderName.value, vMobileNo.value, vEmailID.value, vCityName, vQueryMessage.value, vMicrositeUrl);

                document.getElementById("qSenderName").value = "";
                document.getElementById("qMobileNo").value = "";
                document.getElementById("qEmailID").value = "";
                document.getElementById("qQueryMessage").value = "";

                var win = window.open("http://supertech-supernova.com/supertech-supernova/thanks.htm", "popupWindow", "popupWindow", "width=359,height=365,top=150,left=500,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    win.close()
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
```